# Managing contents in multilingual stores in Magento

Tags: magento

This might be a basic question, I'm still relatively new to `Magento`. I have 2 store views in a magento project. 1 for English (default) and 1 for Japanese. While working with both store views, I noticed how if for example I switch to the Japanese store view, if I redirected to a different page or content on the store, the language goes back to English. How do I prevent the website from going back to the default language every time I change categories/catalogs?

Comment: Did you modify your index.php or .htaccess file to run a specific store?

Comment: Not at all. I didn't change the index or htacess files.

Comment: When both stores use the same domain easiest solution might be to append storecodes to urls in `System Configuration > General > Web > Url Options: Add Store Code to Urls`.

Comment: This works if for example I'm on the homepage but if I went to a different page while the language is in Japanese then I try to change the language to English, it didn't go back to English. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

That is all about Magento Admin setting. While creating Content Pages/Categories/products, there is a option that ask to choose Store View.
You can add content for Cateogries/Product/CMS Pages for each locale. If it is done then you'll be able to see your site content on the basis of current locale. Hence you need to go through Magento Admin first.

Hope it will work for you. Please let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Managing contents in multilingual stores in Magento is easy.

1. Edit/Create Product/Category/Page/Static blocks according to need storeview and put content according to languages in that.
2. Now access pages by store code, if we are using that.
3. In some case we don't find the heading names according to languages so just enable inline translater from admin and do translation specific to store/website.
4. To run Magento store using urls we have both options index.php modifiction and using .htaccess using website and store codes.
5. On running Magento multisite , multistore. We generally face the common urls for media, js and other resources we should use symlink to increase SEO ranking and score.

Please feel free to contact.

Answer (score 0):

Install your language package.

Create products,  categories, pages, and static blocks on the basis of your selected language.

Sometimes translation does not work for few words. In those cases, Inline translation from admin will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Managing content according to store view is very easy.**
follow up below steps for managing content according to Store view.

1. Edit your product or category or your page and static block etc.
2. after that you can see store select left side in product and category and on page you can see feild below url in static block also. select your store view.
3. whater ever you want to change or edit please do according to you.
4. After that save it will apear only on your selected store.

**Note:** *if you not edit any fild by store then it will show default store contents.*